# Web Farm Encryption Troubleshooting

Tags: encryption, msbuild, web-config, rsa

I want to use a shared RSA Key Container for our web farm to encrypt the web.config.

I have followed all the documented steps, **including** using the *-pa* switch to authorize the identity of my app pool on the key.

Has anyone still had problems AFTER authorization? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Error Message:

> Failed to decrypt using provider
>   'RsaSharedProvider'. Error message
>   from the provider: The RSA key
>   container could not be opened.

Provider:

```
    <providers>
        <add name="RsaSharedProvider" keyContainerName="MyKeys" useMachineContainer="false" description="Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt" type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider,System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </providers>
```

Steps:

1. Encrypt the webconfig in an automated build

   ```
   <Exec Command="$(_aspNetRegIisExe) $(_pefApp) $(_websiteDirectory)" />
   <Exec Command="$(_aspNetRegIisExe) $(_pefCon) $(_websiteDirectory)" />
   ```
2. Publish the website to my destination server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to correct one property:

```
useMachineContainer="true"
```